# How do I use findViewById to get a ViewGroup outside OnCreateView in a Fragment?

Tags: android, findviewbyid

I have a `ConstraintLayout` (the child) nested in another `ConstraintLayout` (the parent). I want to be able to call the child from within my `Fragment` class, but outside `onCreateView`. This what I have so far:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        HomeViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        return root;
    }

    ConstraintLayout MyLayout = (ConstraintLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.my_layout);
}
```

Which results in a `NullPointerException`:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
```

I even tried declaring a global `root` variable in the `Fragment` class and assigning the inflated view result to it, but the problem persists.

I cannot place `myLayout` inside `OnCreateView` so I need a solution where I can use it outside of it.

Comment: Why you cant "place myLayout inside OnCreateView" ? You want to find an alternative or throws an exeption?

Comment: Because I have a click listener which depends on MyLayout.

Comment: How long do you suppose a fragment's view lives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue stems from a misunderstanding about when and for how long a fragment's view exists.

Currently, you are assigning your MyLayout variable during construction of your fragment.

According to [the Android documentation on a Fragment's lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/lifecycle) a fragment won't have a view associated with it until after `onCreateView` is called.  Later on in the fragment's lifecycle, the view is destroyed when `onDestroyView` is called.

So, the fragment's view only lives during the intervening time between `onCreateView` and `onDestroyView`.  If you call `getView` before `onCreateView` is called, or after `onDestroyView` is called, you will get null.

So, if you want to set listeners on views, do so either from `onCreateView` or `onViewCreated` and remove them in `onDestroyView`.

Also, if you want to hold onto your view via a member variable, set it in `onCreateView` and null it out in `onDestroyView` and any place you reference it, make sure to check for null first.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare global variable for your view and initialize with a method.

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private ConstraintLayout MyLayout;

    private void init(View v) {
        MyLayout = v.findViewById(R.id.my_layout);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        init(root);
        return root;
    }
}
```

Or you can declare your root and you can find your views with root variable:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private View root;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        init()
        return root;
    }

    private void init(){
        ConstraintLayout MyLayout = root.findViewById(R.id.my_layout);
        .
        .
        .

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can also suggest you ViewBinding. It simplifies the syntax.

https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/use-view-binding-to-replace-findviewbyid-c83942471fc

But definitely learn about basic Android lifecycle and reasons why you cannot access views before onCreateView.